# How to fix my loop to send data from app to api properly on real device?

Tags: java, android

I was working on my homework which i faced a problem, which is about sending data from database with for loop. The whole proccess is that i'm getting some data when user is not connected to internet, then when user connected to internet, app will get all data, and send them one by one to api. I have 2 Problem/Question with this process.

1. My solution work on Emulator on Pc but it won't work on real phone. What's the solution or Better solution to handle this on real device, and i'm also sending some other data when device become online.

Here's The code which is sending my data :

```
    public void sendData() {

    maps = (ArrayList<Map>) appDatabase.getMapDAO().getMaps();
    final int size = maps.size();
    Log.e(TAG, "Map Size Report Before sending in HomeActivity : " + String.valueOf(size));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        long id = maps.get(i).getId();
        if (i != 0) {
            OnlineCordinateRequest onlineCordinateRequest = new OnlineCordinateRequest();
            onlineCordinateRequest.user_id = Integer.parseInt(AppPref.getInstance().getUserID());
            onlineCordinateRequest.lat = maps.get(i).getUser_lat();
            onlineCordinateRequest.lng = maps.get(i).getUser_lng();
            onlineCordinateRequest.methodz = maps.get(i).getMethod();
            onlineCordinateRequest.status = maps.get(i).getStatus();
            onlineCordinateRequest.received_date = maps.get(i).getCreate_time();
            getApi().cordinate(onlineCordinateRequest).enqueue(new Callback<GeneralCallBack>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<GeneralCallBack> call, Response<GeneralCallBack> response) {
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    appDatabase.getMapDAO().deleteIt(id);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<GeneralCallBack> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e(TAG, " Failed at Loop");

                }
            });
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "Created_At " + maps.get(i).getCreate_time());
        Log.e(TAG, "Reporting Remaining Data : " + String.valueOf(size));
        //do something with i
    }
    }
```

2. Is it possible to make some delay between my requests and when it failed just break the loop? Since it's my homework i'm using very low resources like sharing host for my api and i'm sure they will be bad at so many request at, idk 1 min, now consider someone got 40 data in database, and with my loop when device become online, it will try to send 40 instantly... so what i'm trying to do is that i want to make a delay between for almost 10 sec between sending data, to make sure, i won't face another problem.

Please Help me on this, and please answer base on my code since i'm doing this for my homework and i'm not pro. Thanks.

Timerstack Implementation Code:

```
public void sendData() {
    maps = (ArrayList<Map>) appDatabase.getMapDAO().getMaps();
    final int size = maps.size();
    Log.e(TAG, "Map Size Report Before sending in HomeActivity : " + String.valueOf(size));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        long id = maps.get(i).getId();
        if (size != 0) {

            startTimer(i, id);
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "Created_At " + maps.get(i).getCreate_time());
        Log.e(TAG, "Reporting Remaining Data : " + String.valueOf(size));
        //do something with i
    }
}

private void startTimer(int i, long id){
    mTimer1 = new Timer();
    mTt1 = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            mTimerHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    Log.e("Task","Esecuting Home "+i);
                    OnlineCordinateRequest onlineCordinateRequest = new OnlineCordinateRequest();
                    onlineCordinateRequest.user_id = Integer.parseInt(AppPref.getInstance().getUserID());
                    onlineCordinateRequest.lat = maps.get(i).getUser_lat();
                    onlineCordinateRequest.lng = maps.get(i).getUser_lng();
                    onlineCordinateRequest.methodz = maps.get(i).getMethod();
                    onlineCordinateRequest.status = maps.get(i).getStatus();
                    onlineCordinateRequest.received_date = maps.get(i).getCreate_time();
                    getApi().cordinate(onlineCordinateRequest).enqueue(new Callback<GeneralCallBack>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<GeneralCallBack> call, Response<GeneralCallBack> response) {
                            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            appDatabase.getMapDAO().deleteIt(id);
                            stopTimer();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<GeneralCallBack> call, Throwable t) {
                            Log.e(TAG, " Failed at Loop");
                            stopTimer();

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };

    mTimer1.schedule(mTt1, 10000, 3000);
}

private void stopTimer(){
    if(mTimer1 != null){
        mTimer1.cancel();
        mTimer1.purge();
        Log.e("Task","Terminated");
    }
}
```

Comment: which device are you using and what is android version on it.?

Comment: @theShaybi I've tested on android 4.2 and 5

Comment: for delay you can add Timertask to use delay. also which DB you are using. are you sure you are getting data from DB?

Comment: @theShaybi i'll try timertask. about data, the answer is yes, as u saw in code, i'm toasting event after every success request, and after all i've got another activity which i can see the saved data. and it was working on real phone. but data still in some phone is sending and in some phone it's not. about timertask, should i set a timer in for loop?

Comment: @theShaybi can u answer the question for Timertask with a example? i've tried timerstack but timer won't stop and it's keep sending data, i've put my change to bottom of queston.

Comment: delete the loop and send the whole batch, all at once.

Comment: @MartinZeitler how exactly? u mean put all data together and send it to save in 1 record? this is not going to work, bcs it's matter how much data is stored base on time for me and etc...so it's better for app to add seprate data for better reporting in my web panel.

Comment: @Atlas-Pio for the example 40 records, it's 39 requests less, when sending them mapped as an `ArrayList` (this needs a parent model class with annotations). This should also be quicker and cause less traffic. When sending an array and importing/deleting an array, this is not much different than single records. when adding a field `String op` to the model, this could be used for any CRUD operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the example code.

```
public void sendData( ){
    for(databaseList().length){
        //send data
        if(isFailure){
            int dealyTime = 10; //in seconds
            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sendData();
                }
            },dealyTime*1000);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

// to delay every request

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long delay = 1; //seconds
            for(your condition here) {
                //send data here

                Thread.sleep(1 * 1000);
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: it's not really understandable... how your for is using without other parameters, and where this ifFailure came from? please edit your answer...

Comment: you need replace it with your own logic. These are just dummy values.

Comment: well this is not working... it's just like the code i've added at top. it won't repeat the loop but still, it's adding instantly without delay. what's the idea behind if(isFailure)?

Comment: well i found the problem with repeating timer, which it was 3rd parameter i was adding... it's working now base on code i've added. but thanks for mention it anyway. but still look, doing it instantly...

Comment: you want to dealy every request?

Comment: Hey man, this delay worked. but when device became online, app is freezing... how should i fix this? should i use AsyncTask in run()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201950/discussion-between-theshaybi-and-atlas-pio).

Answer (score 1):

For sending them all at once, this would be alike:

```
@NonNull
@POST("maps")
Call<BatchResults> syncMaps( ... );
```

Where class `BatchResults` is the response from the post (ids and results).

With one more field `op`, which indicates what to do with each posted record:

```
public class Map {

    /* either "create", "read", "update", "delete" (or whatever). */
    @SerializedName("op")
    String op = null;
    ...
}
```

And a parent model alike:

```
public class Maps {

    @SerializedName("items")
    private ArrayList<Map> mItems;

    @SerializedName("count")
    private Long count;

    public void setMaps(@NonNull ArrayList<Map> items) {
        this.mItems = items;
    }

    public void setCount(@NonNull Long value) {
        this.count = value;
    }

    @NonNull
    public ArrayList<Map> getMaps() {
        return this.mItems;
    }

    @NonNull
    public Long getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry but i can't really understand whole things you explaind because i'm in learning process but i can also understand what u did in these examples, i'm not sure how i can do it to make it work... can i borrow your time for moments?
in `Call<BatchResults> syncMaps( ... );` what u put in syncMaps? Request Model or ... i really love to understand your way and make it work if it's possible..

Comment: if u've got any discord user , or email, i'll email you to gave u information of my data and how they're sending to api.